# Flatten data in Tableau (not exactly pivot)

Tags: tableau-api

I am looking for flattening the data in Tableau as shown below:

Following is the input format I have:

ID  CUST_ID GROUP   Code

1234    25  HAN1    MD

1234    25  RO      HN

1234    25  WL      C

1234    25  M       NAPP

2345    8   HAN2    MR

2345    8   RO      HN

2345    8   WR      SW

Following is the output format:

ID    CUST_ID   GROUP   Code    Group   Code    Group   Code    Group   Code

1234    25    HAN1      MD       RO     HN        WL       C       M    NAPP

2345    8   HAN2    MR       RO     HN        WR      SW

I know I can achieve that using a programming language but I am not able to get in Tableau. Can anyone please help with that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a calculated field "GROUP_CODE" as below

   [image]
2. Build the view as Below

   [image]

Comment: Thank you Jose.. I also want to get the column names in my view and maintain the sorting list I shown in my example.